# redirect bash script output to a log file from within the script itself

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdout, stdin, stderr

Currently I am running the bash script like this:

```
$ myscript.sh param1 param2 param3 >log.txt
```

and it is outputting the normal information.

### My question is:

how can I output all normal and error information (in, out, err) to a log file from **within** the script itself?

my try is the following but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2>&1
{
    mycommand1 
    mycommand2
    mycommand3
} 2>&1 | tee -a /tempfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exec 1>/tmp/logfile 2>&1
mycommand1
mycommand2
...
```

Comment: it is not working, i placed it just on the second line, and not output file is found after the bash job is finished.

Comment: Then maybe do this: `logdir=$(mktemp -d);exec 1>"$logdir"/log 2>&1`